# How to get cookie in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have been trying to read a cookie in servicestack but get

> "The type 'Cookie' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
>   You must add a reference to assembly ..."

I have alredy added the `System.Web` reference! But still get same error. So if i am in wrong way what is the way to read cookie in ServiceStack ?

```
 public class SocialAccountService : ServiceStack.Service
    {
        private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(SocialAccountService));
        public SocialAccountService()
        {

        }
        public object Any(SocialAccount req_account)
        {
            var cookie = base.Request.Cookies[""];
            ControllerAuthorizationProxy<SocialAccount>.Any(new SocialAccountController(req_account), this);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

> ServiceStack, Version=4.0.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio says you need to add a reference to `System.Net`. I guess your "..." say the same.

Comment: Upps, i read it as System.Web :) But it is System.Net Thanks,